# Passing geolocation from parent to child in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get a geolocation, setstate, then pass it down to a child component. The problem is that the component that needs the state as props gets rendered before the geolocation is set to state. I thought that when the state changes, React would rerender the component that uses that state.

```js
class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
   location: null,
   venues: [],
   markers: []
  }
  this.getCurrentLocation = this.getCurrentLocation.bind(this)
  this.setCurrentLocation = this.setCurrentLocation.bind(this)  
 }
  
        setCurrentLocation(currentLocation) {
  this.setState({location: currentLocation})      
 }

 getCurrentLocation() {
  let self = this; 
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {     
   let updatedLocation = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude
   }
   self.setCurrentLocation(updatedLocation)   
  })
 }
  
        render() {
  const markers = [
   {
    location: {
     lat: this.state.location.lat,
     lng: this.state.location.lng
    }
   }
  ]
  return (
   <div className="main-container">
    <h1>Render a Map</h1>
    <div className="inner-container">
     <div className="map">
      <Map center={this.state.location} markers={markers}/>
     </div>
     
    </div>
   </div>
  )
 }
}
```

This is the component that uses the location

```js
class Map extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)  
 }

 render() {  
  const mapContainer = <div className="map-container"></div>
  const markers = this.props.markers.map((marker, i) => {
   const place = {
    position: {
     lat: marker.location.lat,
     lng: marker.location.lng
    }
   }
   return <Marker key={i} {...place} />
  })
  return (
   <GoogleMapLoader
    containerElement={mapContainer}
    googleMapElement={
     <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={15}
      defaultCenter={this.props.center}
      options={{streetViewController: false, mapTypeControl: false}}>
      { markers }
     </GoogleMap>
    } />
  )
 }
}
```

Thanks for for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't render the child until you have the data.

`{this.state.location && <Map .../>}`

That being said, the Map component should re-render every time its props change, so I'd check in the React dev-tools that the `location` state is indeed changing when you expect it to.